# ResultInfo - java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-api-client

I read the other similar problems but couldn't find a solution.

I implemented this yesterday https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi and it was working fine. Today I have no idea what I messed up in the project. When I enter the fragment and the location is disabled the window to ask me to turn on location does pop up, but no matter how many times I click no it won't go away or if I click yes I'll get in logcat

```
 11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: name.company.newapp, PID: 23652
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {name.company.newapp/name.company.newapp.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4054)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4097)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1497)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlh.zzb(Unknown Source)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zzb(Unknown Source)
11-17 01:02:05.470 23652-23652/name.company.newapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
```

Basically in onActivityResult the `googleClient` is null. As I said yesterday was working. ..

TestLocation fragment:

```
public class TestLocation extends Fragment implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


        public TestLocation() {
        }

        private static GoogleApiClient googleClient;
        private Location mLastLocation;
        private PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (googleClient==null) {
                googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            // Defines the xml file for the fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_activity_fragment, container, false);
            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleClient, builder.build());

            if (result != null) {
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                                // requests here.

                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                                // a optionsDialog.
                                try {
                                    // Show the optionsDialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                    if (status.hasResolution()) {
                                        status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 1000);
                                    }
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    // Ignore the error.
                                }
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                                // settings so we won't show the optionsDialog.
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if ((resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == 1000)) {
                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleClient);
                if (mLastLocation == null) {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleClient, locationRequest, this);
                } else {
                   Log.d("askj","not null");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e("location", "finally");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (googleClient!=null) {
                googleClient.connect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (googleClient!=null) {
                if (googleClient.isConnected()) {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleClient, this);
                    googleClient.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the `static` modifier from the `GoogleApiClient` declaration.

Comment: I removed it, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of the `TestLocation` Fragment?

Comment: What do you mean ? I use it only when I press the button to instantiate it. If the location is on everything is working fine, but the problem happens when the location is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google API reference for the [`GoogleApiClient#disconnect()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#disconnect()) method:

> **public abstract void disconnect ()**
>
> Closes the connection to Google Play services. No calls can be made using this client after calling this method.

You are disconnecting the client in the `onPause()` method, so as soon as you call the `startResolutionForResult()`, your `GoogleApiClient` is no longer valid. You don't need to stop and re-start the client as you would unregister and re-register a `BroadcastReceiver`. From the top of that same page:

> You should instantiate a client object in your Activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` method and then call `connect()` in `onStart()` and `disconnect()` in `onStop()`, regardless of the state.

Comment: Many thanks.  I'll pay more attention in the future at the fragment's life-cycle.

Comment: No problem. I had to check myself. Cheers!